# rhino for equation solving in android studio

Tags: android, math, rhino

Im trying to make an app for school project. the propose of the app is to solve equuations,
the program is working pretty good (it's using newtons method). when i did some research about
how to make a string in to a code, ive found something called rhino, so now im using it to solve
the equation the only problem is when im trying to enter the Math.pow(a, b) into the string i
want to execute, string that look like this give me back this error:

```
String => "(float)2*Math.pow(NaN,2)-1"
----------------------------------------------
Error => "org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: missing ; before statement (<Unknown source>#1) in <Unknown source> at line number 1"
```

now I really didnt get rhino so good,so i tried to find any tutorial about it, and found nothing,
any way, if any one how to make this work, i would really apriciate some help.
Thanks Ido barel.

The full code if anyone need it.

```
private Object place_X_in_func(String raw_func, float num){
        String func = raw_func.replace(" ", "");
        String equation = "(float)";
        int i = 0;
        while(i < func.length()) {
            boolean isPow = false;
            char c = func.charAt(i);
            if(c == 'x' || c == 'X'){
                char v = func.charAt(func.indexOf(c)+1);
                if((int)v == 94){
                    char z = func.charAt(func.indexOf(v)+1);
                    equation += "Math.pow("+String.valueOf(num)+","+z+")";
                    i+= 3;
                    isPow = true;
                }
                else{
                    equation+= String.valueOf(num);
            }
            }
            else {
                equation += c;
            }
            if(!isPow){
                i += 1;
            }
            //System.out.println("Runned "+i+"of "+func.length());
        }
        ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("rhino");
        try {
            System.out.println("EQ => "+equation);
            Object result = engine.eval(";"+equation);
            System.out.println(result);
            return ("R:"+result);
        } catch (ScriptException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return  0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your string isn't valid javascript. Javascript has no datatype casting. If you remove the `(float)` at the beginning of your string it should work. The result of the expression `2*Math.pow(NaN,2)-1` in javascript is a `number`. The result will be returned to java as a `java.lang.Double`.

Comment: I actually changed my project type because of that mistake... I can't believe that. Thanks a lot my friend.